# Как работают библиотеки на других языках

Tags: любой-язык, библиотека

Всем привет! Бывает такое, что библиотеки для одного языка (например, пайтон) пишут на другом (например, C++). Объясните, пожалуйста, как эту либу вообще можно привязать к проекту, если они на совершенно разных языках. Спасибо!

Comment: Очень просто: пайтон сам по себе написан на Си, вот и всё

Comment: [ABI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Двоичный_интерфейс_приложений) и там смотрите по ссылкам Соглашение о вызове и пр.